# log file processing and display with less

Tags: bash, performance, shell

I have a somewhat large log file (150mb) that needs to have some substrings modified before being displayed to the user using less.
So here is what I do:

```
cat file.log | script.sh | less
```

This works but if the file gets updated then the new lines don t appear so instead I do now:

```
tail -f -n +1 file.log | script.sh | less
```

This gives me the entire log file + the new lines too.
The problem is that the tail solution is extremely slow compared to the cat solution.
This phenomenon can be simply reproduced by comparing cat and tail without invoking the script in the middle of the pipes:

```
cat file.log | less
```

is instant vs

```
tail -f -n +1 file.log | less
```

takes some long seconds for less to navigate smoothly.

cat doesn t give me the updates and tail is too slow. Is there a solution that would fit those constraints? thx :)

Answer (score 0):

Piped output is usually buffered. For faster output, you may consider

```
unbuffer tail -f -n+1 | awk '{replace substring here}'
```

The `unbuffer` command comes as a part of `expect-dev` package in Debian based systems.